# jQuery to trigger submitting of different forms based on input being all numbers or just letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I've been trying to do this for hours. Either only one of my forms works or none at all. I can't get the form function or submit function to do anything. it just disables the whole thing and doesn't submit. Any help is appreciated.

Basically I have two forms that I want to submit based on the entry in the first form's input field, "s-webref".

If "s-webref" has input which is all numbers, submit the first form: "property-webref-search".

If not, submit the second form "property-search".

My first form (located on top):

```
        <form name="property-webref-search" id="property-webref-search" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">

            <input type="text" class="text webref" id="s-webref" name="s" value="<?php _e('İlan no veya arama', 'woothemes'); ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('İlan no veya arama', 'woothemes'); ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('İlan no veya arama', 'woothemes'); ?>';}" />

        <input type="submit" class="submit button" name="property-search-webref-submit" id="property-search-webref-submit" value="<?php _e('ara', 'woothemes'); ?>" /> 

        </form>
```

My second form:

```
        <form name="property-search" id="property-search" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">

        <input type="text" class="main-query text" id="s-main" name="s" value="<?php if ( $keyword != '' ) { echo $keyword; } else { _e('Arama...', 'woothemes'); } ?>" onFocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('Arama...', 'woothemes') ?>') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('Arama...', 'woothemes') ?>';}" />
                <input class="view-button" type="submit" value="<?php _e('ara', 'woothemes') ?>" name="property-search-submit" />

        </form>
```

This is the javascript that I used that makes form not work at all:

```
$('#property-search-webref-submit').click(function() {
var searcherz = $("input#s-webref").val();
if(searcherz.match(/^\d+$/)) {
$('form#property-webref-search').submit();
}
else {
$('form#property-search').submit();
}});
```

Comment: wheres the javascript (besides the validation)

Comment: @VeXii Edited to add the failed javascript. although I don't think that would do any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is always submitting, as you are not preventing the default action of the submit button:

```
$('#property-search-webref-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searcherz = $("#s-webref").val();
    if( /^\d+$/.test(searcherz) ) {
        $('#property-webref-search').get(0).submit();
    } else {
        $('#property-search').get(0).submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be doing anything. the first form is always submitted. or at least the code works this way on my page.

Comment: Yes, it's inside        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

maybe the structure of my forms prevent the second one from being able to be submitted? This is exactly what has been driving me crazy for the past 4 hours! the second form doesn't submit anymore after jquery is added.

Comment: I just added alerts to each of the if and else functions and neither of the alerts popped up. the code doesn't get triggered for some reason.

Comment: Changed the code a little bit, but if even alerts don't work, it's something else?

Comment: Did a test of the regex and if/else [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zy9nS/) and that seems to works as expected. Are you sure the click event on that button even fires, and that you got the ID right etc.

Comment: the updated code detects and submits the forms, but the search functions seem to have lost some of the input that used to get submitted. they don't work as they did before.

Comment: Scratch that, the first form doesn't get triggered at all. that's what was changed.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other functions interfering, like a return false somewhere etc.

Comment: I would have to check for that, Thanks a lot for your help so far! The problem is the first form doesn't work even if numbers are entered. I'll try and find the reason why this happens. thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I can't really duplicate the problem, as it's to local, and it has some PHP, and it's probably Wordpress as well, so could be any number of things really. The code above should work on it's own, so who knows where the problem is ?

Comment: The php function was preventing it to work correctly, but your first code was spot on! It works correctly after a few minor adjustments on the site system. Thank you!!!